# CSS background-color on colgroup when scroll is visible

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I've got a page which may or may not contain one or more large and complex table(s). With JQuery I add background-color to both tr and colgroup when hovering over the table(s).

The problem is when I have more than one table, the page is larger than the viewport (scrollbar is visible), and it does NOT affect the first table. I really don't know how to explain it, just run the snippet below in fullscreen and you'll see. Also, this does not happen in IE it seems.

```js
$("table").delegate('td','mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
  var $table = $(this).closest('table');
  if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
    $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
    $table.children("colgroup").children("col").eq($(this).index()).addClass("hover");
  } else {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
    $table.children("colgroup").children("col").eq($(this).index()).removeClass("hover");
  };
});
```

```css
.hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="margin: 60px;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
  <colgroup>
    <col></col>
    <col></col>
    <col></col>
    <col></col>
    <col></col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1a</td>
      <td>2a</td>
      <td>3a</td>
      <td>4a</td>
      <td>5a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1b</td>
      <td>2b</td>
      <td>3b</td>
      <td>4b</td>
      <td>5b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1c</td>
      <td>2c</td>
      <td>3c</td>
      <td>4c</td>
      <td>5c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1d</td>
      <td>2d</td>
      <td>3d</td>
      <td>4d</td>
      <td>5d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1e</td>
      <td>2e</td>
      <td>3e</td>
      <td>4e</td>
      <td>5e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1f</td>
      <td>2f</td>
      <td>3f</td>
      <td>4f</td>
      <td>5f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1g</td>
      <td>2g</td>
      <td>3g</td>
      <td>4g</td>
      <td>5g</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1h</td>
      <td>2h</td>
      <td>3h</td>
      <td>4h</td>
      <td>5h</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1i</td>
      <td>2i</td>
      <td>3i</td>
      <td>4i</td>
      <td>5i</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1j</td>
      <td>2j</td>
      <td>3j</td>
      <td>4j</td>
      <td>5j</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1k</td>
      <td>2k</td>
      <td>3k</td>
      <td>4k</td>
      <td>5k</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1l</td>
      <td>2l</td>
      <td>3l</td>
      <td>4l</td>
      <td>5l</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="margin: 60px;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
  <colgroup>
    <col></col>
    <col></col>
    <col></col>
    <col></col>
    <col></col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1a</td>
      <td>2a</td>
      <td>3a</td>
      <td>4a</td>
      <td>5a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1b</td>
      <td>2b</td>
      <td>3b</td>
      <td>4b</td>
      <td>5b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1c</td>
      <td>2c</td>
      <td>3c</td>
      <td>4c</td>
      <td>5c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1d</td>
      <td>2d</td>
      <td>3d</td>
      <td>4d</td>
      <td>5d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1e</td>
      <td>2e</td>
      <td>3e</td>
      <td>4e</td>
      <td>5e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1f</td>
      <td>2f</td>
      <td>3f</td>
      <td>4f</td>
      <td>5f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1g</td>
      <td>2g</td>
      <td>3g</td>
      <td>4g</td>
      <td>5g</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1h</td>
      <td>2h</td>
      <td>3h</td>
      <td>4h</td>
      <td>5h</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1i</td>
      <td>2i</td>
      <td>3i</td>
      <td>4i</td>
      <td>5i</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1j</td>
      <td>2j</td>
      <td>3j</td>
      <td>4j</td>
      <td>5j</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1k</td>
      <td>2k</td>
      <td>3k</td>
      <td>4k</td>
      <td>5k</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1l</td>
      <td>2l</td>
      <td>3l</td>
      <td>4l</td>
      <td>5l</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What is going on!?

Comment: Indeed, and what disturbs me the most is that if the two (or more) tables where to be truncated to fit the viewport or the viewport is very small, the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: I am not even sure, or have even a single clue, how you managed to break the browser rendering engine, please file a bug! `:)`

Comment: I'm using Microsoft edge, I don't see your any problem here..

Comment: i can't see any problem in your code , i test it on firefox and google chrome

Comment: @Sora: Neither do I. I've tested it in Opera 32, Chrome 44 and IE11. It worked fine in IE, but not the Chromium based browsers.

Comment: Did you run the snippet in fullscreen? It seems to work in smaller viewports and that just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: maybe if you use a newer version of jquery may fix your problem

Comment: I couldn't chose that in my snippet, but I actually use `//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js` on my page. Still the same problem, though.

Comment: what if some plugins in your browser is preventing the code from running ?

Comment: It's not. The code is running, but there are glitches in the rendered result. I have, however, solved this issue bu using different elements and selectors, completely eliminating the use of col and colgroup. I'll post the solution in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I made a workaround with the nth-child(n) selector, thus eliminating the need for col and colgroup.

```
$("table").delegate('td','mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
        $(this).closest("table").find("tr td:nth-child(" + ($(this).index()+1) + ")").addClass("hover");
        $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
    } else {
        $(this).closest("table").find("tr td:nth-child(" + ($(this).index()+1) + ")").removeClass("hover");
        $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
    };
});
```